# Query tables with same column name

Tags: sql-server-2008, multiple-columns, temp-tables

please help

I have 5 temp tables, namely #TEMPTABLE, #TotEmp, #TotEnrol, #NotEnrol and #PercEnrol. 
TEMPTABLE contains the following:
 `Staff Number | Employee_Name | Home_Branch | Enrolledd | Card | Tested` 
 (Enrolledd - indicator of whether employee is enrolled or not - 1/0)
 
TotEmp contains the following (Total number of employees in branch)
 `Home_Branch | Employee` 
 
TotEnrol contains the following (Total number of enrolled employees in branch)
 `Home_Branch | Enrolled` 
 
NotEnrol contains the following (Total number of employees NOT enrolled in branch)
 `Home_Branch | Not_Enrolled` 
PercEnrol contains the following (Percentage of enrolled employees in branch)
 `Home Branch | Percentage`  
 
I would like to do a select which shows the following - AND the percentage enrolled must only be branches under 90% and the results must be grouped by branch.

`Home_Branch | Enrolled (from TotEnrol) | Employee (TotEmployee) | Not Enrolled  (NotEnrol)| Percentage (PercEnrol)`  
I wanted to select * from all tables I need and just put that into a final table, but obviously this duplicate Home_Branch keeps popping up and I'm not sure how to join all of them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question I believe this should work for you:

```
SELECT     T1.Home_Branch,
           T3.Enrolled,
           T2.Employee,
           T4.NotEnrolled,
           T5.Percentage
FROM       #TEMPTABLE T1
INNER JOIN #TotEmp T2 ON T1.Home_Branch = T2.Home_Branch
INNER JOIN #TotEnrol T3 ON T1.Home_Branch = T3.Home_Branch
INNER JOIN #NotEnrol T4 ON T1.Home_Branch = T4.Home_Branch
INNER JOIN #PercEnrol T5 ON T1.Home_Branch = T5.Home_Branch
WHERE      T5.Percentage < 90
```

I have used aliases on the tables so you can specified which table you want the column selected to come from, this will eliminate the 5 copies of `Home_Branch` you mentioned. The table aliases could be named better than `T1, T2, T3 etc`, but your names of your temp tables are already pretty short!

You also mentioned the percentage being less than 90%, hence the `WHERE` clause.

As a side note, you probably didn't need to set up all those temp tables (unless you were specifically told to do it like this) depending on your source data you might have been able to use one statement with `GROUP BY`, sub queries or a couple of `CTEs`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: XN16 - the output looks correct thank you, however I'm getting duplicate results. When I try to GROUP BY Home_Branch I get Ambiguous column name 'Home_Branch'.

Comment: Did SELECT DISTINCT - this seems to have helped. Thanks again :)

Comment: @LisaRieken The ambiguous column name is due to the multiple columns with the same name. Again you can use aliases e.g. `T1.Home_Branch`. Or as you discovered `SELECT DISTINCT` works in this case, but with more complex queries which more columns you won't be able to use it.